# How can I get end of session of texting conversation with Sms-Magic in Salesforce?

Tags: text, salesforce, sms

I need to track the end of session - of a texting conversation using Sms-Magic in Salesforce, and based on session ended - create a task in Salesforce.
But I'm not even sure how I would figure out that the session has ended -
because the conversation might take a few days if there is a time difference between countries - so I cannot determine that a session is only up to an hour for example.
So how can I find the conversation's end, and then based on that create a task through a Flow?.